# A mysterious measurement in the diagram produced by the `layout` package

Tags: margins

The `layout` package

> produces an overview of the layout of the current document

([the `layout` package's user manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/layout.pdf), 2014/10/28, p. 1)

Putting this package to use, the following LaTeX document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

produces the following pdf file

[image: LaTeX document layout]

The legend says that the broken vertical line's distance from the left edge is

> one inch + \hoffset

Where does the 'one inch' setting come from? Is it hard-coded into the LaTeX engine? Why doesn't it have a name like the other layout elements in the diagram?

I'm similarly puzzled with regards to the broken horizontal line's distance from the page's top edge.

Comment: Yes. If you set `\hoffset=0pt`, `\oddsidemargin=0pt`, you obtain a text beginning 1 inch from the left side of the paper sheet.

Comment: @Bernard: Is this measurement hard-coded into the LaTeX engine? Why doesn't it have a name like `\hoffset` or `\oddsidemargin`? Can this value be changed, and, if so, how?

Comment: @Bernard: It's only about 2.1cm, i.e. the reported 62pt then

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Does this mean that if we set \oddsidemargin and \hoffset to 0, it nevertheless applies some negative \ hoffset so as to obtain a physical left margin equal to 62 pt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one inch from the left and the top is a convention built into TeX, although some explanation is necessary. First I'll ignore pdfTeX developments.

By itself, TeX has no notion of “physical page”. It only features `\hoffset` and `\voffset` whose values are written in the DVI file to be interpreted by the device driver (for printing or previewing).

By convention, *all* device drivers for DVI files set the upper left point of the page contents one inch right from the left margin of the page and one inch below the upper margin. Why? Because this was done by the first device driver and the convention is spelled out in the TeXbook.

In contrast to legacy TeX, pdfTeX does have a notion of physical page, but of course its author chose to follow the convention, in order not to invalidate documents and allow them to be compiled with `pdftex` or `pdflatex` with no change.

LaTeX has a different way of setting the page parameters from plain TeX, but it *had* to comply with the overall convention built in the device drivers.

It *could* set `\hoffset` and `\voffset` to -1in, so easing measurements; but this would be abusing the parameters, which should be used only to fix small misalignments due to device driver. LaTeX might have offered an interface for this, but one has to keep in mind that when LaTeX was first issued, many of its users came from plain TeX and *knew* about `\hoffset` and `\voffset`.

In conclusion, you should accept this as an oddity. And use `geometry` if you want to change the page parameters.

<sub>There is another package aimed at this, namely `vmargin`, which plays with `\hoffset` and `\voffset`, setting them to -1in. Look on the site for the problems that arise from this choice.</sub>

Actually, `pdftex` has introduced two parameters, namely `\pdfhorigin` and `\pdfvorigin`, both set by default to 1in, but playing with them is likewise troublesome.